# Dynamically Setting Positional Operator In MongoDb, NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to update a sub-document which is an array in mongodb using array index.
Below is my code, is this possible ? or is their any othr way

```
arrayindex = 3;
Model.update({_id: ObjectId(id), 'array.userid' : ObjectId(userid)},{$set:{"array.arrayindex.points" :20,  }}
```

i want to update 3rd object in subdocument.

**Note :** Above code is not working and when i use $ operator it updates only first matched object in array also `arrayindex` variable can be any value dynamically known

Comment: ``{ $set: { [`array.${arrayindex}.points`]: 20 } }`` in modern JavaScript distributions. All other variations in the marked duplicate.

Comment: Also, really bad idea. You should instead be using the actual ["positional `$` operator"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) and not a **fixed array index**. Presuming that an array is unmodified since your last read of the data so the index has not changed is certain to lead to problems.

Comment: Well i achieved what i wanted in another way using Mongo Aggregation Framework, Thanks for suggestion. will post solution here later as an answer

Comment: The aggregation framework **does not update** documents. So it would be really difficult to get a solution that way. Also, this question is closed so you cannot post a solution here. The solution is what you have been pointed to.

Comment: ok , yes aggregation framework doesn't update , but have done it a two step process  , query by aggregation framework and normal update in its callback sub-documents individually.